# How to use WebRTC to create an application that can stream my voice in real-time?

Tags: node.js, flutter, websocket, socket.io, flutter-dependencies

I need to build a simple app using Flutter and I need to build a server for the back-end using NodeJS. The app needs to be running on 2 phones. On one phone, when I press a button in the app, my voice starts recording in real time and is sent to the server. The server transmits the sound to the other phone from where you can listen to what is being said. Kind of like a walkie-talkie.

Now I cannot use any APIs and/or anything paid, I know I need Flutter WebRTC to record and transmit my voice to the server in real time, and I need socket-io in the server, but I am confused as to how to do it. Flutter's WebRTC website is not clear enough and I am still learning. I also did not get much help on the internet regarding socket-io either. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

So far, I made an app from the directions of a website I found. Here is what I have so far (it's probably nothing):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Start'),
            onPressed: () async {
              // Get access to the microphone and create a local stream
              MediaStream localStream = await MediaDevices.getUserMedia({'audio': true});

              // Create a peer connection
              RTCPeerConnection pc = await createPeerConnection({});

              // Add the audio track to the peer connection
              localStream.getTracks().forEach(
                  (track) async => await pc.addTrack(track, localStream));

              // Establish a WebRTC connection with the server
              // You need to implement your own signaling mechanism here
              // For example, you can use WebSocket, Socket.io, Firebase, etc.
              // You can refer to some tutorials or guides on how to do that
              await connectToServer(pc);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  connectToServer(pc) {}
}
```

I am not sure whether this piece of code sends any audio data to the server. I am a bit confused actually.

Comment: can you please explain your requirements, do you want one to one audio call??